# Send mail to multiple recipients using sendgrid

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, sendgrid

I want to send mail using sendmail to multiple recipients in single call. I am using cakephp 1.3. Sending mail to single recipient works fine. I was wondering if I could send mail to multiple recipients(typically around 2-5 recipients).

```
$this->Email->smtpOptions = array('port'=>'587', 'timeout'=>'30', 'host' => 'smtp.sendgrid.net', 'username'=>'****', 'password'=>'****', 'client' => '***');
$this->Email->delivery = 'smtp';
$this->Email->from = 'Swiso Support <support@swiso.net>';
$this->Email->to = $user['email'];
$this->Email->subject = $title;
$this->Email->template = 'email';
$this->Email->sendAs = 'both';
$this->Email->send();
```

Could I pass an array of recipients to `$this->Email->to` .

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Why not look in CakePHP's manual?

Comment: have you tried comma separated emails in `to` field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Googling "cakephp email" reveals this:

[CakePHP 1.3 cookbook: Email](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1283/Email)

it should give you what you need: There is, for example, the `bcc` field that allows you to send mails to multiple recipients.

The book also has a chapter on [sending multiple messages in a loop.](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1285/Sending-Multiple-Emails-in-a-loop)

Answer (score 1):

I dont know much about CakePHP but Sendgrid provides an easy way for sending single mail to multiple recipients in php and you can convert this code to Cakephp,

Sendgrid provides **`Mail::addTos` method in which we can add multiple mails to whom we want to send our mail**,

we **have to pass associative array of user emails and user names** into `addTos`.

see below example:

```
$tos = [ 
        //user emails       =>  user names  
        "user1@example.com" => "Example User1",
        "user2@example.com" => "Example User2",
        "user3@example.com" => "Example User3"
    ];
    $email->addTos($tos);
```

If you want to see Full example which is provided in sendgrid-php github library then i have included it below, so you can understand the whole example:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php'; // If you're using Composer (recommended)
// Comment out the above line if not using Composer
// require("<PATH TO>/sendgrid-php.php");
// If not using Composer, uncomment the above line and
// download sendgrid-php.zip from the latest release here,
// replacing <PATH TO> with the path to the sendgrid-php.php file,
// which is included in the download:
// https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php/releases

$email = new \SendGrid\Mail\Mail(); 
$email->setFrom("test@example.com", "Example User");
$tos = [ 
    "test+test1@example.com" => "Example User1",
    "test+test2@example.com" => "Example User2",
    "test+test3@example.com" => "Example User3"
];
$email->addTos($tos);
$email->setSubject("Sending with Twilio SendGrid is Fun");
$email->addContent("text/plain", "and easy to do anywhere, even with PHP");
$email->addContent(
    "text/html", "<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with PHP</strong>"
);
$sendgrid = new \SendGrid(getenv('SENDGRID_API_KEY'));
try {
    $response = $sendgrid->send($email);
    print $response->statusCode() . "\n";
    print_r($response->headers());
    print $response->body() . "\n";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: '.  $e->getMessage(). "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No. 
I have been looking into this too (using Sendgrid), and unless you want to use the bcc field, there isn't a way to do it in the same call. 
You shouldn't worry about just sending them in a loop though.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($recipients as $recipient) {
    $this->Email->to .= $recipient['email'] . ",";
}
```

Sending a BCC is a better way of doing this, if you don't want the recipients being able to see to whom you sent it to. In that case it would be

```
$this->Email->bcc
```

instead of

```
$this->Email->to
```

Answer (score 0):

http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1284/Class-Attributes-and-Variables

*to*: Address the message is going to (string). Separate the addresses with a comma if you want to send the email to more than one recipient.

*cc*:   array of addresses to cc the message to.

*bcc*:  array of addresses to bcc (blind carbon copy) the message to.

Examples:

```
$recipients = array("email1@gmail.com", "email2@yahoo.com");
$this->Email->to = implode(",", $recipients);
$this->Email->cc = $recipient;
$this->Email->bcc = $recipient;
```